# PHP Server site for reCaptcha form submission always shows error

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm having some problems with my reCaptcha v2 implementation. I'm playing around with an AJAX request to validate the reCaptcha.

form_submission.php:

```
<?php 
$secret = "----mykey----";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$postvars = array("secret"=>$secret, "response"=>$recaptcha, "remoteip"=>$ip);
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$captcha_success=json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
  
if ($captcha_success['success']==false) {
echo 'ERROR';
}
else {
echo 'SUCCESS';
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
button=document.getElementById("saveForm");

button.addEventListener('click', submitaction);

function submitaction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'form_submission.php',
    data: {captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()}, 
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);
    grecaptcha.reset();
    }
    }
   
    );
}
```

It just gives me "ERROR" all the time. Can someone help me?

Comment: What does the contents of `$data` look like? Is there a hint in there about why it's failing?

Comment: I used strval() and file_get_contents() on it and apparently it's empty.

Comment: You're presumably getting some error response another way, then. Use the cURL functions to check response code, etc.

Comment: _"I used strval() and file_get_contents() on it"_ - on what? No idea what you even mean by that. Just have your script echo $data as a first debugging measure, and then see what that actually contained.

Comment: @CBroe: As I said, it contains nothing. It echoes back empty. However, I checked ```curl_exec($ch)``` and it states: "Warning: curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in form_submission.php"

Comment: Well then go check what `curl_error` has to report.

Comment: @CBroe: ```curl_exec($ch)``` states: "Warning: curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in form_submission.php"

Comment: Ok, I found out, that I have to close the cURL session after the success check. Now however, ```curl_error```gives me back that the connection to www.google.com has failed due to refused connection on port 443.